# Zend2: Limiting e-mail validation to only one error message?

Tags: validation, email, zend-framework2

I have the following validation setup for an email field:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name'     => 'email',
    'required' => true,
    'filters'  => array(
        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'name'    => 'StringLength',
            'options' => array(
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'min'      => 1,
                'max'      => 255,
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'name'    => 'EmailAddress',
            'options' => array(
                'messages' => array(
                    \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME => 'You did not enter a valid e-mail address.' 
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
)));
```

The problem is that if I type in something like: "bla@bla", I get the following triggered errors:

```
You did not enter a valid e-mail address.
The input does not match the expected structure for a DNS hostname
The input appears to be a local network name but local network names are not allowed
```

It's way too tedious to do this:

```
array(
    'name'    => 'EmailAddress',
    'options' => array(
        'messages' => array(
            \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID => 'You did not enter a valid e-mail address.' , 
            \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => 'You did not enter a valid e-mail address.' , 
            \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME => 'You did not enter a valid e-mail address.' , 
            \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_LOCAL_PART => 'You did not enter a valid e-mail address.' , 
            \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_MX_RECORD => 'You did not enter a valid e-mail address.' , 
            \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_SEGMENT => 'You did not enter a valid e-mail address.' , 
        ),
    ),
)
```

Is there no better way to do this?

*UPDATE*

Also, this doesn't work. I still end up with:

```
 You did not enter a valid e-mail address.
 The input does not match the expected structure for a DNS hostname
 The input appears to be a local network name but local network names are not allowed
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setMessage` on the validator without a second parameter will set all the messages:

```
$email = $factory->createInput(array(
    'name'     => 'email',
    'required' => true,
    'filters'  => array(
        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'name'    => 'StringLength',
            'options' => array(
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'min'      => 1,
                'max'      => 255,
            ),
        )
    ),
));

$emailValidate = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
$emailValidate->setMessage('You did not enter a valid e-mail address.');
$email->addValidator($emailValidate, TRUE);

$inputFilter->add($email);
```

Not sure if the following also works, but you could give it a try:

```
    array(
        'name'    => 'EmailAddress',
        'options' => array(
            'message' => 'You did not enter a valid e-mail address.'
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Afaik this would result in three times the same message (as that was my experience with ZF2 in the early stage)

Comment: Okay, that's what the second parameter of `addValidator` is for. This means only 1 message will be shown.

Comment: It doesnt! It only spits out one error. Thanks! That's the most elegant solution!

Comment: Ah, I was missing that. That would be the break chain on failure. Perhaps that's good to explain too :)

Comment: @coderama you can set the message & that true flag with the config as well, so you don't need to use those objects if you use the array style already.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is as follows:

```
'message' => array(
    \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME=>'Email WRONG!',
),
```